Is there any way to have content of mask elements in respected pages while creating distribution in typo3 version 11,12?
While creating new distribution in typo3 v11 and 12, pagetree imports fluid content element by own but mask elements came with blank fields..! Below i attach 2 screenshots of fluid content element and mask content element after creating new distribution.
Mask content element:
https://i.sstatic.net/trE17ory.png
Fluid content element:
https://i.sstatic.net/M68rEhVp.png
I tried to import manually in typo3 v12 but the frontend blocks and by using typo3 v11 the manual import doesn't succeed..
I wanted to have content in mask element too after creating new distribution.

Did you check the database, if the mask contentelements where imported properly. Maybe your mask configuration does not work in the newer version of mask.

@Mogens Yes i do checked database and there mask elements i have created is imported successfully.
And i found on AI that says importing mask element directly will import blank values and importing manually leads problem in rendering front-end in specifically typo3 v11 and 12.
